# Excel 2010 Pivot Tables - Subtotal as an Average of Sums

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that takes a resources % utilisation each month for each project they are on, shows it as a SUM, and sumarises by what department they are in. This looks like:

```
                   Jan-15          Feb-15
Department         Subtotal        Subtotal
   Joe Bloggs      20%             10%
   Fredd Bloggs    60%             30%
```

I want the Subtotal for Department to show the AVERAGE of the percentages shown in the pivot table (so above it would be 40% for Jan-15 and 20% for Feb-15). However, if I select the format as AVERAGE, it returns the AVERAGE of all the data behind the pivot table, which gives me different figures as each person may be working on several projects.

Is there any way I can get the Subtotal to calculate differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I'm trying to figure that one out too. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Same issue here...solution likely requires VBA so maybe add the VBA tag to get more eyes on it.